# How can i change a pixel value from a grayscaled image using Opencv 2.3?

Tags: c++, image, opencv

When i read a grayscaled image using for example in Opencv  2.3:

```
Mat src = imread("44.png" ,0);
```

How can i access the pixel value of it?

I know if its RGB i can use:

```
std::cout << src.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[0].
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since a grayscale image contains only one component instead of 3, the resulting matrix/image is of type `CV_8UC1` instead of `CV_8UC3`. And this in turn means, that  individual pixels are not 3-vectors of bytes (`cv::Vec3b`) but just single bytes (`unsigned char` or OpenCV's `uchar`). So you can just use:

```
src.at<unsigned char>(i, j)
```