# opencv - shrink objects to pixels

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am processing such an image as shown in Fig.1, which is composed of an array of points and required to convert to Fig. 2.

*Fig.1 original image*

[image: Fig.1 original image]
*Fig.2 wanted image*

[image: Fig.2 wanted image]

In order to finish the conversion, firstly I detect the `edge` of every point and then operate `dilation`. The result is satisfactory after choosing the proper parameters, seen in Fig. 3.

*Fig.3 image after dilation*

[image: Fig.3 image after dilation]

I processed the same image before in MATLAB. When it comes to shrink objects (in Fig.3) to pixels, function `bwmorph(Img,'shrink',Inf)` works and the result is exactly where Fig. 2 comes from. So how to get the same wanted image in opencv? It seems that there is no similar `shrink` function.

Here is my code of finding edge and dilation operation:

```
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
using namespace cv;

// Global variables
Mat src, dilation_dst;
int dilation_size = 2;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    IplImage* img = cvLoadImage("c:\\001a.bmp", 0);                 // 001a.bmp is Fig.1                              

    // Perform canny edge detection
    cvCanny(img, img, 33, 100, 3);

    // IplImage to Mat
    Mat imgMat(img);
    src = img;

    // Create windows
    namedWindow("Dilation Demo", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    Mat element = getStructuringElement(2,                          // dilation_type = MORPH_ELLIPSE
                  Size(2*dilation_size + 1, 2*dilation_size + 1),
                  Point(dilation_size, dilation_size));

    // Apply the dilation operation
    dilate(src, dilation_dst, element);
    imwrite("c:\\001a_dilate.bmp", dilation_dst);
    imshow("Dilation Demo", dilation_dst);

    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1- [Find all the contours](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#findcontours) in your image.

2- Using [moments](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=moments#moments) find their center of masses. Example:

```
/// Get moments
vector<Moments> mu(contours.size() );
for( int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ )
{ mu[i] = moments( contours[i], false ); }

/// Get the mass centers:
vector<Point2f> mc( contours.size() );
for( int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ )
{ mc[i] = Point2f( mu[i].m10/mu[i].m00 , mu[i].m01/mu[i].m00 ); }
```

3- Create zero(black) image and write all the center points on it.

4- Note that you will have extra one or two points coming from border contours. Maybe you can apply some pre-filtering according to the [contour areas](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#contourarea), since the border is a big connected contour having large area.

Comment: I found the code [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/moments/moments.html) but I don't understand what does `mc[i]` mean. Could you show an example of your step 3, that is how to write the points according to `mc[i]`

Comment: mc is a vector of points. you should create an image same size with your original one, then change pixels with image.at<uchar>(i,j) = 255; where i,j are the points taken from mc. Refer to this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9104869/how-can-i-change-a-pixel-value-from-a-grayscaled-image-using-opencv-2-3). Search for "changing pixels in opencv" if it doesn't solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very fast, but I implemented the morphological filtering algorithm from *Digital Image Processing, 4th Edition* by William K. Pratt. This should be exactly what you're looking for.

The code is MIT licensed and available on GitHub at [cgmb/shrink](https://github.com/cgmb/shrink).

Specifically, I've defined `cv::Mat cgmb::shrink_max(cv::Mat in)` to shrink a given `cv::Mat` of `CV_8UC1` type until no further shrinking can be done.

So, if we compile *Shrink.cxx* with your program and change your code like so:

```
#include "Shrink.h" // add this line
...
dilate(src, dilation_dst, element);
dilation_dst = cgmb::shrink_max(dilation_dst); // and this line
imwrite("c:\\001a_dilate.bmp", dilation_dst);
```

We get this:

[image: image after binary shrink]

By the way, your image revealed [a bug in Octave Image](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?44396)'s implementation of bwmorph shrink. Figure 2 should not be the result of a shrink operation on Figure 3, as the ring shouldn't be broken by a shrink operation. If that ring disappeared in MATLAB, it presumably also suffers from some sort of similar bug.

At present, Octave and I have slightly different results from MATLAB, but they're pretty close.